# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in View. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to make searching on table users but have got error in view on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View:
> /opt/lampp/htdocs/abonamenty/resources/views/users/index.blade.php)

And on the localhost error 404 after click search button.

> "Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. The
> link on the referring page appears to be incorrect or outdated. Tell
> the author of this page about the problem. If you think this is a
> server error, contact your administrator."

This is part of my controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $data = User::sortable()->paginate(5);
    return view('users.index', compact('data'))->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}

public function search(Request $request)
{
    $search = $request->get('search');
    $data = DB::table('users')->where('surname', "%$search%")->paginate(5);
    return view('users.index', ['users' => $data]);
}
```

My routes:

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::resource('roles', 'RoleController');
    Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
    Route::resource('permissions', 'PermissionController');
    Route::resource('products', 'ProductController');
    Route::get('/search', 'UserController@search');
    Route::get('data', 'UserController@index');
    Route::get('posts', 'PostController@index');
});
```

My view:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>Zarządzanie kontami użytkowników</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <form action="/search" method="get">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="search" name="search" class="form-control">
                        <span class="input-group-prepend">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Wyszukaj</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('users.create') }}"> Utwórz nowego użytkownika</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>

    @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <p>{{ $message }}</p>
        </div>
    @endif


    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">@sortablelink('id', 'Numer')</th>
            <th scope="col">@sortablelink('name', 'Imię')</th>
            <th scope="col">@sortablelink('surname', 'Nazwisko')</th>
            <th scope="col">@sortablelink('showname', 'Nazwa wyświetlania')</th>
            <th scope="col">@sortablelink('email', 'Email')</th>
            <th>Rola</a></th>
            <th width="280px">Akcja</a></th>
        </tr>
        @foreach ($data ?? '' as $key => $user)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ ++$i ?? '' ?? '' }}</td>
                <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $user->surname }}</td>
                <td>{{ $user->showname }}</td>
                <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
                <td>
                    @if(!empty($user->getRoleNames()))
                        @foreach($user->getRoleNames() as $v)
                            <label class="badge badge-success">{{ $v }}</label>
                        @endforeach
                    @endif
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('users.show',$user->id) }}">Wiecej informacji</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('users.edit',$user->id) }}">Edytuj użytkownika</a>
                    {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE','route' => ['users.destroy', $user->id],'style'=>'display:inline']) !!}
                    {!! Form::submit('Usuń', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>
    {!! $data ?? ''->appends(request()->except('page'))->render() !!}

    <!--{!! $data ?? ''->render() !!}-->

    <p class="text-center text-primary"><small>ARTplus 2020</small></p>
@endsection
```

Comment: In your view you need to check and see what your `$data` variable is. You can check by using the `dd` command (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-dd). It should be returning a LengthAwarePaginator based on the docs https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination#paginating-query-builder-results. If it isn't an it is null you will run into problems where your are doing `$data ?? ''`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change the search method

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

public function search()
{
    $search =Input::get('search');
    $data = DB::table('users')->where('surname', "%$search%")->paginate(5);
    // Also we can check using print_r($data); die(); 
    return view('users.index', ['users' => $data]);
}
```